# handling Json value in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload files in my ASP.NET MVC application. In the controller action I `return Json(true)` if the file upload is a success or `Json(false)` if not.

In the UI however, I don't see any indication if `Json(false)` was returned. Eg. tst1.html was not uploaded but it still shows up as uploaded like the other files. See below:
[image]

Here is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
                if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(fileData.FileName) == ".zip")
                    {
                        var zipFile = Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
                        fileData.SaveAs(zipFile);

                        FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(zipFile);
                        ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(fs);

                        foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
                        {
                            if (zipEntry.Name.EndsWith(".htm") || zipEntry.Name.EndsWith(".html"))
                            {
                                return Json(true);
                            }
                        }
                        fs.Close();
                        fs.Dispose();
                        System.IO.File.Delete(zipFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
                        fileData.SaveAs(fileName);
                        return Json(true);
                    }
                }
                return Json(false);
    }
```

How can I capture the value returned from the controller action and show the appropriate error message/indicator on the View?

Comment: can you show us the actual code for the controller ?

Comment: Edited the original post with the controller code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the dynamic ViewBag in controller

```
ViewBag.Result = "Success";
```

Then on View,

@if(ViewBag.Result == 'Success') { ... }

EDIT: Using MVC2, I think you can use ViewData

```
ViewData["Result"] = "foo";
```

On View, you get the value

```
<%: ViewData["Result"] %>
```

EDIT2 : OK, the best way is to actually have  model object.

```
class YourViewModel {
     public string Result {get; set; }
}
```

Then, on you controller, you pass the filled model to the view

```
return Json(new YourViewModel { Result= "whatever" });
```

Then, in the view you can call Model.Result

Try this,

regards

Comment: Is ViewBag availabe in MVC 2.0?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. In the controller should I pass Json(true/false) and ViewData? Also, how should I evaluate this value on the View. Sorry, I am very new to MVC...